# Prove that every eigenvector of exp(A) is also an eigenvector of A

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, matrix-exponential

In Gerald Teschl's book on ODE's, he states the following:

> **Lemma 3.3** A vector u is an eigenvector of A corresponding to the eigenvalue $\alpha$ if and only if u is an eigenvector of exp(A) corresponding to the eigenvalue $e^{\alpha}$.

I can clearly see one way of this argument.  However, given an arbitrary eigenvector u of exp(A), I am unable to prove that u is necessarily an eigenvector of A.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true in general. Let $A = \begin{bmatrix} 4\pi i & 0\\ 0 & 2\pi i\end{bmatrix}$. Then $exp(A) = Id$ and $v = \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$ is an eigenvector of $exp(A)$ but not of $A$.

Comment: How did you compute exp(A) to be the identity?

Comment: @user334137 Because $A$ is a diagonal matrix, to exponentiate it is to simply exponentiate its diagonal entries, and $e^{2\pi i} = e^{4\pi i} = 1$, from Euler's formula. In general, you need the eigenvalues of A to not differ by $2\pi i$ in order to get the result stated in your question. I recommend chapter 2 of the book "Lie groups, Lie Algebras, and Representations - An Elementary Introduction" by B. Hall for the basic results concerning matrix exponentials.

Comment: @user334137 If $A$ is diagonal, then $e^A = \textrm{diag}(e^{a_{ii}})$

Comment: Ah yes I see.  I apologize for the trivial question.